# What causes SignInManager.SendTwoFactorCodeAsync to return false?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin

Documentation on the new Microsoft Identity Framework seems a bit sparse. I'm currently modifying the standard project template, and I came across some curious behavior when trying to sign in users with two factor authentication.

We're only allowing 2FA via SMS, so I bypassed the option for users to select how they want their code. Instead, when a user with 2FA and a verified phone number tries to log in, they trigger this code:

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: true);
switch (result)
{
    case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
        if (!await SignInManager.SendTwoFactorCodeAsync("Phone Code"))
        {
            TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "We could not verify your account. Please try again.";
            return RedirectToAction("Error", "Error");
        }
        return RedirectToAction("VerifyCode", new { Provider = "Phone Code", ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
    // other cases
}
```

Most of the time, this works fine. But after a user logs off, the first time they log back on again, `SendTwoFactorCodeAsync` returns false and they're directed to the error page.

What scenarios would cause `SendTwoFactorCodeAsync` to consistently fail the first time it's called for a logged out user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I forgot that the O in Owin stands for Open. The source code is available to answer this question:

```
public virtual async Task<bool> SendTwoFactorCodeAsync(string provider)
{
    var userId = await GetVerifiedUserIdAsync().WithCurrentCulture();
    if (userId == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    var token = await UserManager.GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync(userId, provider).WithCurrentCulture();
    // See IdentityConfig.cs to plug in Email/SMS services to actually send the code
    await UserManager.NotifyTwoFactorTokenAsync(userId, provider, token).WithCurrentCulture();
    return true;
}
```

This is from the `SignInManager`, so that call to `GetVerifiedUserIdAsync()` is the same as calling `SignInManager.GetVerifiedUserIdAsync()` from your application.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the solution was. I am having the same behavior as in your question, but the answer really does not reveal the solution.

Comment: @DustinLaine That's the function code. So it returns false only when userId is null. In other words your user isn't being recognized for some reason.

Comment: Thanks, yes I am just not sure why. Login first time fine, sign out and attempt login again and fail. That method is true then false, pulling out the `GetVerifiedUserIdAsync` I get the guid and null. Seems oddly similar to your question.

Comment: @DustinLaine it's a problem with the usermanager not finding the ID for some reason. you can bypass this by generating the 2FA code with the email from the model.email. then send the code with using NotifyTwoFactorTokenAsync. This way you know for sure you have the ID and avoid all this

Answer (score 0):

Just convert this vb code to C#. I'm too lazy to do it but you get the idea.

```
   Dim result = Await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout := False)
   Select Case result
     Case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification    
         Dim xUser = UserManager.FindByEmail(model.Email)
         Dim TwoFA_code = UserManager.GenerateTwoFactorToken(xUser.Id.ToString, "Email Code")
         Dim TwoFA_Result = UserManager.NotifyTwoFactorToken(xUser.Id.ToString, "Email Code", TwoFA_code)

         Return RedirectToAction("VerifyCode", New With {
                    returnUrl,
                    model.RememberMe
                })

    End Select
```